# XeTeX with CJK: wrong font for numero sign

Tags: fonts, xetex, cjk, libertine

I'm using XeTeX in a MiKTeX 2.9 environment on Windows. Recently, I've added the xeCJK package to a larger document for including a short passage in Chinese. This, however, caused (among others) the numero sign to be displayed in the wrong font: it automatically switches to MingLiU instead of Linux Libertine. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[indentfirst=false]{xeCJK}
%\usepackage[fallback,indentfirst=false]{xeCJK}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Variant=01]{Linux Libertine O}
\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}
%\setCJKfallbackfamilyfont{rm}{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[russian,ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

漢語大詞典 Test test
\No 3

\end{document}
```

Can I prevent this somehow, for instance, by explicitly selecting a font before \No or by deactivating the automatic selection of the CJKmainfont (it is only a short passage, which I could easily enclose by a macro)?

Besides "\No" I also tried \textnumero from the textcomp package, which yielded the same result.

Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me (without using xeCJK)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Variant=01]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\MingLiu{MingLiU.ttf}

\usepackage[russian,ngerman,american]{babel}

\begin{document}

{\MingLiu 漢語大詞典} Test test
\No 3

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Inactivate xeCJK for the time being and redefine `\No`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage[indentfirst=false]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Lucida Grande}
\setCJKmainfont{Kaiti SC}

\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{№}{{\makexeCJKinactive №}}
\let\No №

\begin{document}

漢語大詞典 Test test
№3 \No 3
漢語大詞典 Test test
\end{document}
```

I've used Lucida Grande for better showing that the right font is selected.

[image]

You might just redefine `\No` with

```
\protected\def\No{{\makexeCJKinactive^^^^2116}}
```

instead of the three lines above, but using the Unicode character directly would not work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a mistake that `xeCJK` treats `№` (U+2116) as a CJK full width left puctuation. This mistake is introduced in `xeCJK` version 3.0.3 (r323 at ctex-kit project). I'll fix it.

And before the bug is fixed, you can use

```
\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{Default}{"2116}
```

to solve the problem.

---

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[indentfirst=false]{xeCJK}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Variant=01]{Linux Libertine O}
\setCJKmainfont{MingLiU}

\xeCJKDeclareCharClass{Default}{"2116}

\begin{document}
漢語大詞典 Test test
\textnumero 3 №3
\end{document}
```

---

Note:

Herbert's solution does work but it disables all features of `xeCJK`, including proper line breaking. If you have only several CJK characters to typeset, it is the solution. However I don't think it is a good way if more than one paragraph is to be typeset.

egreg's quick fix is better than Herbert's, but `newunicodechar` is an overkill.